# @Import vs @ContextConfiguration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration, spring-test

Is there any difference in usage of the annotations? Both the annotations allow to use multiple `@Configuration` classes to create an `ApplicationContext`. From their docs `@ContextConfiguration` seems to be more suitable for test configuration and comes from an artifact for tests (`spring-test`), however, I haven't found the actual difference.

Thank you for any thoughts!

Comment: `@ContextConfiguration` is only usable in tests in other code it doesn't do anything. `@Import` is useless on a test and will only be useful on `@Configuration` classes to import other configuration classes (with `@ImportResource` you can import XML configuration files).

Comment: @M. Deinum hi, thanks! but what is the purpose of it then? I may use `@Import` - and this is it

Comment: As stated to `@Import` (aka include, load etc) other java configuration classes. For instance those not covered by component scanning (or maybe you disabled component scanning for `@Configuration` files). Or to create a separate configuration for test which `@Import`s the original configuration so that you can override beans ...

Comment: @M. Deinum ok, I got the first idea. but in the second I could simply put `@Import` on test class, why to use `@ContextConfiguration` here? sorry if I'm being stupid:)

Comment: Because as I also already stated, `@Import` is only useful (and functional) on `@Configuration` classes. It won't do anything on a test class, the only thing it does is take up a line of code.

Comment: @M. Deinum awesome, now I see. thank you very much!

Comment: @Deinum - Wow thanks - I got the point it's just the other way around. But I have to disagree, using @Import(TestConfig.class) on my Test will import that Beans, if they are not defined in my AppConfig. Which is picked up by SpringBootTest. And that made me crazy - because if my AppConfig has that Bean defined, the Imported is ignored. Makes no sense. So don't do that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`@Import`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Import.html) and [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) are for different use cases and cannot be used interchangeability.

The `@Import` is only useful for importing other `@Configuration` files and is only useful (and afaik) and functional on `@Configuration` classes. When putting the `@Import` on a test class it will be no good as it won't be processed.

```
@Configuration
@Import(PersistenceConfig.class)
public class MainConfig {}
```

Using `@Import` can be useful if for instance you have disabled component scanning for `@Configuration` classes or you need an `@Configuration` class from a package not covered by your component-scan.

**Note:** There is also [`@ImportResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) which does the same for older XML based configuration files.

The reverse is valid for `@ContextConfiguration` as that is only useful on Spring based test classes (tests ran with the `SpringRunner` for jUnit 4). It is used to supply the test with the configuration parameters to make up the test configuration. It can be a collection of XML, javaconfig (or a combination thereof).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration( classes = {MainConfig.class, TestConfig.class})
public MyTest {}
```

It also allows to specify what to use to load those configuration (amongst others).

Comment: a note: `ContextCongifuration` can be used either with XML or Java configurations: >  As of Spring 3.1, context loaders may choose to support either path-based or class-based resources.

Comment: Well... you can actually annotate a test class with `@Import` when using Spring Boot. ;-) https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-excluding-config

Comment: @SamBrannen but does it behave exactly the same?

Comment: This answer need correction. `@Import` can be used on Test class as well to import TestConfiguration.

Comment: "When putting the @Import on a test class it will be no good as it won't be processed" ==> this is false. this annotation works perfectly on a test class, associated to @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) annotation.

Answer (score 20):

in Spring Boot `@Import(SomeConfiguration.class)` **adds** configuration class to existing context. It is useful with test slices:

```
@DataJpaTest
@Import(SomeConfiguration.class)
class TestSomething(){...}
```

Here you have access to repositories and your beans from SomeConfiguration class.

`@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeConfiguration.class)` mean use **only this** configuration , which could not work with eg. `DataJpaTest`.